# Convert Mail User to Remote User Mailbox in Hybird Environment

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server, office365

I have created 3 users in exchange, using the regular "Create new Mailbox User" account.

I am sort of new to the exchange hybird with Office 365, and wanted to know if anyone knew of a powershell command to convert a "Mail User" to a "Remote User Mailbox"?

[Mail User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxLO.jpg),
[Remote User Mailbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DffLo.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution Open Exchange Power Shell and run each of the following commands separate:

Enable-remotemailbox "[username]" -remoteroutingaddress [username]@lifepro.com
Get-remotemailbox "[username]" | FL *address*